# Covert Numpy Array of Strings to float aftrer Truncating

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array gven below:

```
array([[' 0.12E'],
       [' 0.00F'],
       [' 0.00F'],
       ..., 
       [' 0.00G'],
       [' 0.00G'],
       [' 0.00G']], dtype=object)
```

i need to remove that E F and G and covert each element in the array to Float. How do i do it??

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
Use `numpy` string types to automatically trim the last character.  Then convert to `float`
If you can trust that all entries are 6 characters long and end in a character that needs to be trimmed:...

```
a.astype('<U5').astype(float)

array([[ 0.12],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ]])
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.DataFrame.replace` with `regex=True` to remove non-digits, then convert to float.

```
pd.DataFrame(a).replace('[^\d\.]', '', regex=True).astype(float).values

array([[ 0.12],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ],
       [ 0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = pd.Series(a[:, 0])
a = s.str.strip().str[:-1].astype(float).values.reshape(-1, 1)
print (a)
[[ 0.12]
 [ 0.  ]
 [ 0.  ]
 [ 0.  ]
 [ 0.  ]
 [ 0.  ]]
```